# Same module is being imported in different files

Tags: python, import, module

Is it a bad practice to do this:

In first.py:

```
import second
import mymodule
```

In second.py:

```
import mymodule
```

`mymodule` is being imported in both files and first.py imports second.py. Is it possible to somehow import the `mymodule` just once? It's not a big deal, it's just not elegant nor Pythonic IMO.

Comment: It's not a bad practice to import modules. Each module should be able to satisfy it's own requirements, without relying on the modules that call it. It helps keep the code more modular.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`mymodule` is only run once; every module that imports it shares the same copy. It's fine. Just be careful if you have any cyclic imports (A imports B imports A, or A imports B imports C ... imports A), because those can cause subtle initialization order problems and mess you up.