# Python import modules in another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, global, python-import, python-module

I'm currently re-factoring a project (formerly big one file) into several seperate python files, each of which runs a specific part of my application.
Eg, `GUIthread.py` runs the GUI, `Computethread.py` does some maths, etc etc.

Each thread includes the use of functions from imported modules like `math`, `time`, `numpy`, etc etc.

I already have a file `globalClasses.py` containing class definitions for my datatypes etc, which each .py file imports at the start, as per recomendation here: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules.htm . This is working well.

What I would like to do is have all my 3rdparty module imports in the `globals` file as well, so that I can write, for example, `import math` once but have all of my project files able to use `math` functions.

**Questions:**

**1. Is this possible?**

**2. Is it a good idea/is it good Python practice?**

My current solution is just to put

```
import math 
import time
import numpy
...
```

(plus imports for all the other modules I'm using as well)

at the top of every file in my project... But that doesn't seem very tidy, and it's easy to forget to move a dependency's import statement when moving code-chunks from file to file...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Same module is being imported in different files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792145/same-module-is-being-imported-in-different-files)

Comment: understood that calling `import module` multiple times doesn't cause an actual repetition of the import work; I was just wondering if it's possible to avoid the repetition of writing the code `import module` . Thanks for the link though

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yeah I guess there is a more elegant way of doing this which will save redundant line of code. Suppose you want to import some modules `math, time, numpy`(say), then you can create a file `importing_modules`(say) and import the various modules as `from module_name import *`, So the `importing_modules.py` may look something like this:

**importing_modules.py**

```
from math import *
from numpy import *
from time import *
```

**main.py**

```
from importing_modules import *
#Now you can call the methods of that module directly
print sqrt(25) #Now we can call sqrt() directly in place of math.sqrt() or importing_modules.math.sqrt().
```

Comment: Just as a small comment, this is really handy if you have many imports in a jupyter notebook and the notebook size is slowing everything down. Definitely outweighs the possibility of bugs and/or confusion about namespace.

Answer (score 10):

The other answer shows how what you want is (sort of) possible, but didn't address your second question about good practice.

**Using `import *` is almost invariably considered bad practice.** See ["Why is import * bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad) and ["Importing * from a package"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) from the docs.

Remember from [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) that *explicit is better than implicit*. With explicit, specific imports (e.g. `from math import sqrt`) in every module, there is never confusion about from where a name came, your module's namespace includes only what it needs, and bugs are prevented.

The downside of having to write a couple `import` statements per module does not outweigh the potential problems introduced by trying to get around writing them.