# large numbers of python import statements at the beginning of my main file. can I put them in their own script?

Tags: python, import

I have a lot of import statements at the start of my main entry point for my fastapi application (around 50 imports). I am looking to clean up the code if possible. Can I put them all in their own script something like `importedlibraries.py` and then reference my main application with `from importedlibraries import *`?

Is there a recommended way to deal with this scenario?

Comment: What you suggested yourself should be possible and seems like a fine solution to me.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794859/python-import-modules-in-another-file

Comment: Thanks for the info! And the link. That didn't crop up when I searched earlier.