# openpyxl: get the xml source code of a worksheet WITHOUT zipfile

Tags: python, excel, xml, lxml, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
```

Is there any way to retrieve the xml code representing the `ws` object?
NOTE: I want to avoid using the `zipfile` module. Instead, I'm trying to extract the xml **directly** from `ws`.

I read the `openpyxl` source code and was playing around with `lxml` - with no success.

Comment: If `zipfile` would solve the problem, why don't you just use it? Avoiding a particular standard module seems like an odd requirement.

Comment: First, I need to edit a workbook with `openpyxl`. Then, I want to replace a part of the xml file defining one of the worksheets. The problem is that `openpyxl` already uses `zipfile` in the background. Unzipping again after the xlsx has been "re-zipped" and saved is a very poor choice performance-wise.

Comment: There isn't any XML that represents the Worksheet object, which is why there are parsers and writers for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Instead of extracting the xml by unzipping the saved workbook, you can capture it while the workbook is being saved. The `wb.save` method makes use of the `ExcelWriter` class, which I modified to suit this purpose:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.writer.excel import *

class MyExcelWriter(openpyxl.writer.excel.ExcelWriter):
    def write_worksheet(self, ws):
        ws._drawing = SpreadsheetDrawing()
        ws._drawing.charts = ws._charts
        ws._drawing.images = ws._images
        if self.workbook.write_only:
            if not ws.closed:
                ws.close()
            writer = ws._writer
        else:
            writer = WorksheetWriter(ws)
            writer.write()
        ws._rels = writer._rels
        
        # my addition starts here
        if ws.title == 'My Sheet':
            with open(writer.out, 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
                xml_code = file.read()

            # my code continues here...
        # my addition ends here

        self._archive.write(writer.out, ws.path[1:])
        self.manifest.append(ws)
        writer.cleanup()

openpyxl.writer.excel.ExcelWriter = MyExcelWriter
```

The `write_worksheet` function creates a temporary xml file, whose path is stored in `writer.out`.
Remember that `from <module> import *` [is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28795304/12601647) – use with caution.

Comment: Or just take control of the temporary files that are used, but really, looking at the zipfile is easier.

Comment: You're right that `zipfile` would be more straightforward, but please read my comment under the original post.

Comment: I read it and don't think it's valid.