# Python: Optimizing Module Imports

Tags: python, import, module

This is a theoretical question that I have been looking for an answer to for sometime, but could never actually find it.

Suppose I have my main file `main.py` which has `import numpy as np` and `import helper`.

If I have a helper file `helper.py`, could I use `np` in `helper.py`, because I already imported it in `main.py`, and the only time I would ever use `helper.py` is via `main.py`, resulting in `numpy` always being imported?

Comment: Duplicate of [Same module is being imported in different files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18792145/2301450)?

Comment: What happened when you tried the experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) states:

> The import statement combines two operations; it searches for the
>   named module, then it binds the results of that search to a name in
>   the local scope.

If the import occurs at the top of a module, local scope will be global - i.e. *local to the module*.

On the plus side, normally imports will only occur once. Python will search the cache for imports before carrying out an import and will create a reference to a previously imported module if it finds it. This saves have to load a second copy - there's no harm (generally) in having the import statement in both modules.

> The first place checked during import search is sys.modules. This
>   mapping serves as a cache of all modules that have been previously
>   imported, including the intermediate paths.

Additionally, from the [FAQs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=global#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules):

> How do I share global variables across modules?
>
> The canonical way to share information across modules within a single
>   program is to create a special module (often called config or cfg).
>   Just import the config module in all modules of your application;